# Netbeans drag and drop builder doesn't work (Kubuntu 12.04, Netbeans 7.0)

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, drag-and-drop

I need to build gui for my application in Netbeans **(I'm not interested in other solutions, for example Eclipse and its plugins cause my teacher demands my app to be written in Netbeans only).**

I created a Netbeans Java project and added JPanel and JFrame form but drag and drop builder doesn't work. I still see this:

[image]

and even if I try to drag (for example), JButton and drop it on JPanel nothing's happen.

What should I do? Use latest Netbeans 7.1 on Kubuntu 12.04.

***My IDE log:*** http://pastie.org/private/lige9jjnsi2fq7bx08purw

And see also this:

[image]

Comment: Wise teacher, you have :) Could you go to View -> IDE Log and copy the IDE Log (perhaps pastebin.com, since it is really large), that might give some hints, on whats going wrong.

Comment: Do you see that red "stop" icon slightly to the left of the "INS" label in the bottom right of your picture? That icon indicates some error occurred, you can click it for details. Combined with the IDE log that should provide a couple of clues.

Comment: @Tim Roes: Ok, I added IDE log, thanks for helping

Comment: @user268396: I didn't notice that, it says: http://s6.ifotos.pl/img/zrzut-ekr_raqqpaw.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Debian/Ubuntu

This might to be a bug at the moment in the Debian/Ubuntu Version. I found the following two bug reports, that seem to match your bug:

- http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=653915
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/netbeans/+bug/944857

To sum the bug reports up: There doesn't seem to be a real fix to that yet, but for some people starting NetBeans with the following command is a workaround:

```
$ netbeans -cp:a /usr/share/java/xercesImpl.jar
```

Unfortunately I don't have a Debian bases system here at the moment, so I cannot test, if it would work for me.

## Gentoo

It seems that the same bug also effects Gentoo Linux. I could workaround there by emerging `dev-java/batik` and then starting NetBeans with:

```
$ netbeans-7.1 -cp:a /usr/share/batik-1.7/lib/batik-ext.jar
```

The versions in this command might need to be exachanged, if you have installed different versions of the applications.

Comment: You're genius, I mean it! :D It worked for me, at least for a very simple test, (just dragged an dropped JButton and it worked). So, I think I will run Netbeans like you wrote and I hope I won't see this errors never again, cheers:)